# What will be the behaviour when ProcessPoolExecutor & Multiple Workers started using Gunicorn (FastAPI) are used together?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fastapi, gunicorn, process-pool

I have a sample code of FastAPI that utilizes ProcessPoolExecutor during start up:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    applog.info(f"{ENGINE_MODULENAME} app is starting executor...")
    process_pool_size = constant.PROCESS_POOL_SIZE if constant.PROCESS_POOL_SIZE > 0 else None
    app.state.executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(process_pool_size)
    applog.info(f"Executor initiated with {app.state.executor._max_workers} workers.")

    preloaded_models = {}
    app.state.model = preloaded_models
    applog.info("Application loaded with serving models.")

    preloaded_data = {}
    app.state.data = preloaded_data
    applog.info("Application loaded with serving data.")

    yield

    del preloaded_models
    del app.state.model
    applog.info("Application removed serving models.")

    del preloaded_data
    del app.state.data
    applog.info("Application removed serving data.")

    applog.info(f"{ENGINE_MODULENAME} app is shutting down executor...")
    app.state.executor.shutdown()
    applog.info("Executor shut down successfully.")


app = FastAPI(title=__name__, lifespan=lifespan)
```

I will start the application via gunicorn:

```
gunicorn --bind :8002 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --workers 4 --timeout 300 --preload --chdir interface app.main:app
```

For each gunicorn worker, the same logs will print that `Executor initiated with the max number of workers (in this case, ProcessExecutor workers`

Would this behaviour overload my application and cause it to crash since all 4 workers are printing the same logs?

What is the correct way of combining ProcessExecutor code with Gunicorn to reach the optimal load management in an environment with multiple CPU cores?

I have tried running the above code but did not put it through load testing yet as the process is very expensive in the current workflow designed.